# Получить текст элемента из select

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<select multiple>
<option value="1">Выберите вариант 1</option>
<option value="2">Выберите вариант 2</option>
<option value="3">Выберите вариант 3</option>
</select>
```

Есть такой `select`, нужно определять текст опции при смене варианта, например при смене на "Вариант 2" будет выскакивать его "Выберите вариант 2"

```
console.log($(this).text());
```

не работает, использую select'ы от materialize

У меня идет событие `$("select").on('change', function() {});` и this это кликнутый элемент, например, `console.log($(this).val());` выдает правильный `value`

Comment: `console.log($(this).text());` - и что по-твоему это значит? и откуда ты взял это?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский у меня идет событие `$("select").on('change', function() {});`
и this это кликнутый элемент, например,`console.log($(this).val());`
выдает правильный `value` кликнутого элемента

Comment: так и надо добавлять в вопрос, а то подумают, что ты пишешь бред))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всё что надо это брать [option:selected](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0_select), https://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/

```js
$("select").on('change', function() {
  // Это если селект один на странице 
  var selectedText = $('select option:selected' ).text();
  
  // Для конкретного селекта, где выбираются options
  //var selectedText = $('option:selected', this).text();
  console.log(selectedText);  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple>
    <option value="1">Выберите вариант 1</option>
    <option value="2">Выберите вариант 2</option>
    <option value="3">Выберите вариант 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: `$(this).find('option:selected')` ?

Comment: @Igor добавил для случая, когда надо брать у конкретного селекта

Answer (score 0):

```js
    document.querySelector('select').addEventListener('click' , (event)=>{
        (event.target.tagName === 'OPTION') &&
        console.log(event.target.text);
    }, true);
```

```html
<select multiple>
    <option value="1">Выберите вариант 1</option>
    <option value="2">Выберите вариант 2</option>
    <option value="3">Выберите вариант 3</option>
</select>
```